# I can't animate a canvas generated block

Tags: html, canvas

I am using HTML5 canvas and wrote the following program:

```
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
    var animation = 20;
    var i = 0;

    function draw(x) {
        context1.fillStyle = "#FFF000";
        context1.fillRect(x,30,100,100);
    }

    function animate() {
        while (i>1000) {
                context1.clearRect(0,0,1000,200);
                draw(animation);
                if (animation >= 980){
                        animation = 20;
                }
                animation++;
        }
    }

    animate();
```

This following block I am hosting on a web page at http://ec2-54-83-18-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com/.
If you looked at the website, you can see, nothing is displayed.
However, if you take out "animate();" and put in "draw(some integer);", it displays a roughly yellow cube like it's supposed to, but without animation.

I am trying to get it to send the yellow block along the x axis from 20 pix to 980 pix (my screen is 1000 pix width). I hope it would move indefinitely, but I made sure it terminated before because I wondered if that was the problem. It didn't work.

As you can see from my URL, I am using Amazon EC2 web services. My instance is Ubuntu.

My instance size is micro (which brings trouble with Minecraft sometimes).

My OS is Windows 8.

I hope any of that helped.

Thanks.

Edit: I also hope to get this off soon as can be because on my website is my server ip. I don't want a hacker going around trying to pull a prank on my server or worse, not that they will find anything worth their time(because of its domain name, its pretty remote, so I want to keep it that way until I'm ready).

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with canvas, and more to do with how JS in the browser works.

Because just about everything in just about every browser runs in the same thread (that includes running JS, updating the elements on the page, and then drawing the updates), it means that if you put a dozen things inside of a for loop, expecting them all to be drawn, it won't actually happen until the JS stops running.

This includes animating DOM elements, changing CSS, etc.
If you make the changes in a for loop, you won't see them until the end of the loop (and the end of the calling function, and it's calling function, etc).

What you actually want to do is set a timer of some sort.

There are lots of ways of doing that.  The new standard (supported by practically every browser that supports `<canvas>` is `requestAnimationFrame(animate)`, where `animate` is your function, which will animate exactly one frame.

You get more frames of animation by calling the same function again.

```
var keepGoing = true;

function animate () {
    /* ... draw stuff */
    if (keepGoing) requestAnimationFrame(animate); // calling itself
}

animate();
```

Or, alternatively (and preferably)

```
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

RequestAnimationFrame does the work of setting up the timeouts for you; it also does something that you can't do, which is try to lock the animation to 60fps, and lock that drawing in time with your monitor's refresh cycle (something you'd never have access to in the browser, but is basically "V-Sync").

You can also do this manually, by managing `setTimeout`s or a `setInterval` (or `setImmediate`, if supported/polyfilled), but then you don't have the other benefits which come from the specialty call.

The moral is that pretty much any JS from an in-browser standpoint, should either be reactionary (event/message-based) or asynchronous (callback/promise/wrapped-generators, et cetera).
Most server-side JS should, as well, for that matter.